# PXE boot very slow when PXE server is virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, pxe

As I read in questions here and on the Internet, PXE and Virtualbox don't seem to like each other too much. My problem is the following:
I have a virtualized machine which hosts the DHCP and PXE server for 10 native clients. They are rebooted roughly every 10 mins and on each reboot, they need to boot a small linux (the initrd is ~4MB). Before, I had a native machine running and booting via PXE was very fast. Now, looking at the output of nload, I only get 500kbit/s whenever one machine is booting. The machines are connected via a GBit switch, so that can't be it. Also, when testing the connection speed to the outside, I have the full bandwidth available. Is VBox just unable to deal with large amounts of UDP packets? Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was one of the underlying system. I got strange messages regarding some IRQ errors. Adding "noirqdebug" to the kernel params did the trick - now things are fast again.